# How can two instances of System.Type with same name be loaded simultaneously and be different?

Tags: c#, debugging, .net-core

I've run into very weird situation. I'm running a `dotnet test <testing project>` with custom simplistic test adapter. Test method is marked with that Fact attribute. How can it be that attribute evaluated type and type, accessible in runtime via `typeof` have same qualified name, but are not equal?
[image: problem screenshot]

Comment: Type identity is tricky, this is the kind of problem you'd get when an assembly gets loaded more than once with Assembly.LoadFile().  Harder to explain in .NETCore and a unit test runner that nobody has heard of.

Comment: Well, @HansPassant, at least you gave me an idea to investigate the things further. Thanks!